# How to OAuth and use the Filter Query twitter4j Android

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

Basically I want to search for a query in the live stream of tweets (but i only want to know how many tweets are received within a time period) with the twitter based Twitter4j in Android say:

```
FilterQuery query = new FilterQuery();
String[] keywordsArray = { "python", "java", "scala" };
query.track(keywordsArray);
```

But how to authenticate using oauth and what url are to be called to perform these actions?
And is there a way to save the stream of tweets into an arraylist only to find it's .length?
Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("*************");
cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("*************");
cb.setOAuthAccessToken("*************");
cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("*************");

TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
```

Full example: http://davidcrowley.me/?p=435